# A Sine Wave with a Sine Wave Inside

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

How do you graph a sine wave that is "squiggly" in the pattern of a sine wave as such that there are points of inflection in the sine wave as if it was a sine wave itself? If anyone can provide a formula, how do you alter it to have 3 sine waves?

Thank you for your help.

I apologize for my crude drawing, but here is what I'm saying:

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you considered a function like $\sin x+\frac 13\sin(7x)$?

Comment: That isn't what I am looking for. That is like if the sine wave is _majorly_ oversampled.

Comment: Are asking how to plot $\sin(\sin(x))$?

Comment: Do you mean something like $sin(x) sin(40 x)$ ?

Comment: Not exactly. Will post crude drawing.

Comment: So, you're asking how to find an equation given a plot, not the other way around then?

Comment: Try something like $sin(x)+\frac{1}{5} sin(8 x)$

Comment: Correct, Chester,

Comment: $y=5\sin(0.5\pi\sin(3\pi\sin(x))) + \sin(20\pi x)$

Comment: That's close, but it isn't exactly what I described. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do $y=10 \sin (x) + \sin (10x)$  You can play with the parameters to make it like you want.  Here is a [link to Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2010%20sin%20%28x%29%2Bsin%2810x%29)

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it and got this: y=sin(x)+(sin2πx)

Comment: If the frequencies are not a rational multiple of each other, the curve will not repeat.  That is why I used a factor $10$.  It may not matter to you.